# Browser bookmark to Batch file opens .bat in browser instead of running normally

Tags: windows-explorer, browser, batch-file, bookmarks

I'm new to super user, please go easy on me. :)

I created a batch file to search for a USB drive with a specific label and open an html file in the default browser (Edge) which works great. I had a bookmark to this in my browser's bookmarks bar which was working fine, when clicked the batch file would run normally (in CMD), but suddenly clicking the browser bookmark results in the contents of the .bat file displaying in the browser instead of running. I tested this in Chrome and also in IE11. Chrome does the same as Edge and opens the .bat in a new tab whereas IE11 acts as intended, when clicking the bookmark it runs the batch file in the command prompt.

I have recently updated Edge which is where my bookmark was located and did not previously try this in Chrome (I had no reason to try it till now). What could have changed to cause this and how can I fix it please? Of course I can simply use a shortcut on the desktop or start menu or assign a keyboard shortcut to a .lnk file (better as this is something I use every day), but out of principle I want to know why this is no longer working.

Version info: Windows: 10 Pro 19042.630 IE: Version 11.630.19041.0 Edge: Version 87.0.664.55 (Official build) (64-bit) Chrome: Version 87.0.4280.88 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Answer (score 0):

For Chrome, you must have had `"Open on specific pages"` on for this problem to consistently happen.
To disable, go to `Chrome Settings.`
Go to the `Search Bar` and search: `"On Startup"`.
Then select `"Continue where I left off."`
Or:

```
"New Tab Page"
```

> If this does not fix the problem, please let me know. :)

Comment: Hi babysimpau, that doesn't have any effect on the issue I'm afraid. This behaviour did not happen in the old version of Edge with the blue icon, only since the Chromium based version with the multi-colored icon. I originally asked this question in Stack Overflow and (in addition to being chastised for asking in the wrong place) was informed this new behaviour is correct because it would be a security concern if Edge Favourites (bookmarks) were able to directly launch other apps (like they used to).